# I can't finish thread (runnable), how it is?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

```
Thread thread;     

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_yippi);  
final Handler hn=new Handler();
final TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        text.settext("hi");
    }
};
thread = new Thread()
{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(1750);
                hn.post(r);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
    thread.start();
thread.stop();}
```

The code here. I can not stop the runnable thread. Also, `thread.stop()` and `thread.destroy()` are deprecated. Can somebody help me? And also I don't understand how to stop the thread with the `thread.interrupt()` method. What's wrong?

Comment: the docs answer your question almost exactly http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: How about formatting your code before posting it here? It is not so difficult (most IDE's provide an automatic way to do it), and it shows that you at least care about the fact that we have to read that code... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaDoc for Thread.stop() lists the following article as explanation for why stop() is deprecated: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

> Most uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it is to stop running. To ensure prompt communication of the stop-request, the variable must be volatile (or access to the variable must be synchronized).

interrupt() is more suitable to stop some Thread from waiting for something, that is probably not coming anymore. If you want to end the thread, it's best to let its run() method return.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable to stop the thread and use it in `while(boolean)` instead of `while(true)`.

Comment: variable should be defined as volatile

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.interrupt() to trigger the InterruptedException within your thread. I've added code below that demonstrates the behavior. The mainThread is where your code would be and the timer Thread is just used to demonstrate delayed triggering of the interrupt.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Thread mainThread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean continueExecution = true;

                while (continueExecution) {
                    try {
                        sleep(100);
                        System.out.println("Executing");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        continueExecution = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        mainThread.start();

        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("Stopping recurring execution");
                mainThread.interrupt();

            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interrupt method of Thread to try stop a thread, like below code.
May be it`s useful to you.

```
public class InterruptThread {

    public static void main(String args[]){

      Thread thread = new Thread()
      {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    System.out.println("Thread is Runing......");
                    sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // restore interrupted status
                System.out.println("Thread is interrupting");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
       };
      thread.start();

      try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }

     System.out.println("Will Interrupt thread");
     thread.interrupt();
  }
```

}